Tracking Transactions in raydium pool for specific mint
i want to build something which similar to buy bots in telegram. I want to track buy transactions for specific mint, i was wondering which methods i should use because i tried couple things and i couldn't filter the transactions for specific mint. I was getting all the transactions in raydium pool, how can i filter this?
